# Describing a String type in Ada

Tags: ada, ada2012, spark-2014

I have a type similar to:

```vhdl
type ID is new String (1 .. 7);
-- Example: 123-456
```

How can I specify that format in code, either with Ada or SPARK?

I was thinking about `Static_Predicate`, but the condition that the string must start with 3 positive integers followed by a dash followed by another set of 3 positive integers can't be described with a `Static_Predicate` expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a `Dynamic_Predicate` for this:

```vhdl
type ID is new String (1 .. 7)
  with Dynamic_Predicate => (for all I in ID'Range =>
                               (case I is
                                   when 1 .. 3 | 5 .. 7 => ID (I) in '0' .. '9',
                                   when 4               => ID (I) in '-'));
```

I'm using this quite a bit myself, but I mostly make the types subtypes of `String` instead of actual new types.

Comment: When I try that, I get the error: "of" should be "is".

Comment: I _think_ GNAT lets you use just `Predicate` (it works out whether to use `Dynamic_Predicate` or `Static_Predicate` for itself)

Comment: Messed up. Corrected now.

Comment: @SimonWright, but that is GNAT specific behaviour, and unlikely to get into the standard, as it makes it unclear if a subtype is valid for use in a case statement or not.

Comment: Great, thanks. it works. I created a separate validation function and used that as the `Dynamic_Predicate`.